# Multi-directional ether

Tags: optics, interferometry, aether

In the Michelson-Morley experiment,the two beams of light should be directed at right angles in order to test the existence of ether, but that postulate is based on the prediction that ether has only one direction, is it possible to predict that it may have a multiple direction. I know that ether has been proven to be not found, but just in case I want to know if such hypothesis would apply to the problem..

Comment: as far as I know the aether wasn't moving at all, it was the earth's movement within this aether. So in fact, it would only have one direction.

Comment: If you follow the example of optics, a multi-directional aether would be birefringent, i.e. one wouldn't have seen one set of interference lines but two. In general it would lead to a very blurry looking world with everything showing up twice most of the time.

Comment: I should reread the details of the exp. And focus more, but now I'm thinking that nothing is really empty, even vacuum, though I don't have enough info, but it's just like that,, so light is propagating in a certain medium, since we can't really create something that is totally empty, but then one can think that however this not empty thing, light doesn't change its speed, so the medium doesn't affect the light, so the medium might be unchanging but to me nothing is actually fixed, so.. Light is really mysterious.

Comment: Or there should some new concept for it

Comment: Could they observe photons?!